# Expression can't be evaluated, because there is a negative frame on top of the stack

Tags: c#, .net, ftdi

I'm creating a test station program in C# where I communicate with a test pcb through a ftdi to Uart cable. All works fine but sometimes my application crashes.
Through debugging I found that the crash occures on the FTDI object InterfaceIdentifier because the Expression can't be evaluated, because there is a negative frame on top of the stack. What I'm trying to do in this line is

`ftStat = myMod.Write(txbuf, bytestowrite, ref numBytesWritten`

I can check that the Port is open.

What I don't understand is that sometimes it runs for several days and on other times it just crashes after a few hours while doing the same stuff.

Comment: Might some specific transferred data  cause that "negative frame" condition? Why would that "negative frame" occur, whatever that is?

Comment: but the data that is being transfered at that moment is always the same. It's not possible to become negative at some point

Comment: I doubt that a byte can be negative, so I guess that "negative frame" means something else. I have no experience with what you are doing, so I don't know.

Comment: Sure it is not "native frame on top of the call stack"? That is not the error, it just means that the debugger currently can't evaluate expressions to display its values.

Comment: I think you are right. Any recommendation on how to find the error. The windows error log is no help unfortunately.